# Javascript/Jquery JSON object to array inside object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I see many topics on this site, but every one deal with single Array.

My need is to convert every object with number as key to array.

For exemple,
I have an object like :

```
{
  "parent":{
    "0":{
      "child":false
    },
    "1":{
      "child":false
    },
    "4": {
      "child":false
    }
  }
}
```

And i would like

```
{
  "parent": [
    {
      "child":false
    },
    {
      "child":false
    },
    null,
    null,
    {
      "child":false
    }
  ]
}
```

This is an exemple, my object can be really deep and content many object like this, so i need a generic function.

**UPDATE**

My try sor far using code of @Nenad Vracar :

```
function recursiveIteration(object) {
    var newob = {};
    for (var property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (typeof object[property] == "object"){

                var result = {};
                var keys = Object.keys(object[property]);
                if ($.isNumeric(keys[0])) {
                                console.log("======> "+property+" is table");

                 for (var i = 0; i <= keys[keys.length - 1]; i++) {
                  if (keys.indexOf(i.toString()) != -1) {
                    result[property] = (result[property] || []).concat(object[property][i]);
                  } else {
                    result[property] = (result[property] || []).concat(null);
                  }
                                }
                                newob[property] = result;
                                 recursiveIteration(object[property]);
                        }       


                newob[property] = object[property];
                recursiveIteration(object[property]);
            }else{
                newob[property] = object[property];
            }
        }
    }
    return newob;
}
```

And the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3q0tz3f2/1/) for live try

Thanks you guys !

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve it ?

Comment: what is null, null?

Comment: What do you mean by deep?Is there any nesting to nth level?

Comment: @Rahul Arora null, null, is index 2 and 3.

Comment: @RIYAJ KHAN I mean i can have object, in object in object, etc...

Comment: Please provide your generic object

Comment: It content more then 10.000 lines i can't. And it can change.. That why i need a generic function

Comment: Do all nested objects have properties (keys) like array indices?

Comment: No. just some object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
var data = {
  "parent": {
    "0": {
      "child": false
    },
    "1": {
      "child": false
    },
    "4": {
      "child": false
    }
  }
};


var convert = function(data) {

  // not an object, return value
  if (data === null || typeof data !== 'object')
    return data;

  var indices = Object.keys(data);

  // convert children
  for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++)
    data[indices[i]] = convert(data[indices[i]]);

  // check if all indices are integers
  var isArray = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    if (Math.floor(indices[i]) != indices[i] || !$.isNumeric(indices[i])) {
      isArray = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  // all are not integers
  if (!isArray) {
    return data;
  }
  // all are integers, convert to array
  else {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0, n = Math.max.apply(null, indices); i <= n; i++) {
      if (indices.indexOf(i.toString()) === -1)
        arr.push(null);
      else
        arr.push(data[i]);
    }
    return arr;
  }

};

console.log( convert(data) );
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nua6Lxmj/) with the data you provided in the update.

Comment: Hey man, that's perfect, thanks you so much, and thanks to everyone try to help me !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Object.keys()` and one `for` loop

```js
var data = {"parent":{"0":{"child":false},"1":{"child":false},"4":{"child":false}}}, result = {}

var keys = Object.keys(data.parent);
for (var i = 0; i <= keys[keys.length - 1]; i++) {
  if (keys.indexOf(i.toString()) != -1) {
    result.parent = (result.parent || []).concat(data.parent[i]);
  } else {
    result.parent = (result.parent || []).concat(null);
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thats the idea ! But as i said i need a generic function for doing it, key are never the same, etc...But thanks, i'll try to do it based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

You might achieve this job with a very simple recursive Object method as follows. Any valid nested object (including arrays) within an object structure will be converted into an array, in which the properties are replaced with indices and values are replaced by items.

```js
Object.prototype.valueToItem = function(){
  return Object.keys(this).map(e => typeof this[e] === "object" &&
                                           this[e] !== null     &&
                                    !Array.isArray(this[e]) ? this[e].valueToItem()
                                                            : this[e]);
};

var o = {    name: "terrible",
         lastname: "godenhorn",
             cars: ["red barchetta", "blue stingray"],
              age: 52,
            child: {    name: "horrible",
                    lastname: "godenhorn",
                        cars: ["fiat 124", "tata"],
                         age: 24,
                       child:{    name: "badluck",
                              lastname: "godenhorn",
                                  cars: ["lamborghini countach"],
                                   age: 2,
                                 child: null}}},
a = o.valueToItem();
console.log(a);
```

Ok modified to the OP's conditions but still generic as much as it can be.

```js
Object.prototype.valueToItem = function(){
  var keys = Object.keys(this);
  return keys.reduce((p,c) => typeof this[c] === "object" &&
                                     this[c] !== null     &&
                              !Array.isArray(this[c]) ? keys.every(k => Number.isInteger(k*1)) ? (p[c] = this[c].valueToItem(),p)
                                                                                               : this[c].valueToItem()
                                                      : this
                     ,new Array(~~Math.max(...keys)).fill(null));
};

var o = {
      parent: {
               0: {
                  child : false
               },
               1: {
                  child : false
                  },
               4: {
                  child : {
                            0: {
                               child : false
                            },
                            3: {
                               child : false
                               },
                            5: {
                               child : false
                            }
                  }
               }
      }
};
a = o.valueToItem();
console.log(JSON.stringify(a,null,4));
```

Comment: This will convert every object to an array, effectively losing all property names.

Comment: @janje Exactly... this is what it does. That's why it's called `valueToItem()`

Comment: That is not what the OP wants to do. Check my answer for the correct behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, this is not exactly what i want, but your code is interesting. If i had a better knowledge on javascript i could edit it for my need, but i'm not good enought for it :/

Comment: @A. Rossi OK have corrected the above code according to what i think you want :)